# Корректно ли предложение: "Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода — стоит разобраться!"

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

1) Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода — стоит разобраться.

Может, правильно оформить в виде двух предложений:

2) Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода? Стоит разобраться.

Возможно, оба варианта корректны?

Comment: Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода, — стоит разобраться.***

Тире оставляем, перед ним ставим запятую.

**Придаточное изъяснительное в препозиции и представляет собой косвенный вопрос, интонация усиливается.**

[СПП с придаточным изъяснительно-объектным](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/slojnopodchinennyie-predlojeniya-pridatochnyim-68394.html)  В предложениях же с союзом **что** и с относительным подчинением придаточные могут быть и **препозитивны**. *Выделительный* характер таких инверсированных конструкций (особенно при замене указательного слова то анафорическим это) очевиден. Например: *Что он дурной человек, я не могу сказать, так как не знаю его, но что он мне не нравится, об этом я говорил тебе уже тысячу раз* (Чехов). 
В предложениях с относительным подчинением при препозиции придаточных ***вопросительное значение усиливается.*** Например: ***Когда он прибудет,— неизвестно (Чехов).***

Comment: А тире с запятой по каким соображениям?

Comment: Запятая закрывает придаточное, а тире больше интонационное. Без него тоже можно.

Comment: А можно без запятой (но с тире)?

Comment: Сказать вам честно?) Я бы поставила только тире, без запятой. Тире, на мой взгляд,  выполняет двойную работу. Но меня смутило чеховское предложение в сборнике Розенталя "Когда он прибудет, - неизвестно" и убедила статья по поводу препозитивных придаточных изъяснительных с вопросительным значением.

Answer (score 1):

> Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода — стоит разобраться.

В таком виде предложение плохо воспринимается. Варианты исправления:

**Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода — в этом стоит разобраться.**

**Чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода? Стоит разобраться.**

**Стоит разобраться, чем же нас так привлекла маслянистая мякоть этого плода.**